# Dags not being picked up as per its schedule if the schedule interval is less than min_file_process_interval value in Airflow.cfg of v1.10.2

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

In airflow.cfg file, I configured min_file_process_interval value to be 120 seconds. The dag had schedule interval to run after every minute. 
But it is being scheduled only after every 120 seconds (as per min_file_process_interval value).  Is this expected ?

I changed the min_file_process_interval to 200 seconds, then the dag schedule started being picked up after 200 seconds. 
Just to clarify,if the case is opposite, i.e. dag schedule interval is 2 minutes and min_file_process_interval is 1 minute, then the dag will run fine as per its schedule.
Below is my dag:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 5, 14),
    'retries': 0,
}

dag = DAG('print', catchup=False, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='*/1 * * * *')

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='echo `date` , ',
    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per airflow [documents](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Scheduler+Basics):

> In cases where there are only a small number of DAG definition files, the loop could potentially process the DAG definition files many times a minute. To control the rate of DAG file processing, the `min_file_process_interval` can be set to a higher value. This parameter ensures that a DAG definition file is not processed more often than once every `min_file_process_interval` seconds.

It means airflow will process at every `min_file_process_interval` seconds. Thus, you should set your DAG schedule interval to be the multiples of `min_file_process_interval`.

Comment: Yes, i think that is right. However, the dag schedule need not be in multiples of min_file_process_interval. It has to be greater than min_file_process_interval value.

Comment: Correct, it is not necessary to be multiples but just for best practice.

Comment: I faced this problem as explained below and had to revert the config changes.
I observed that if a task completes in (say) 1 minute and my "min_file_process_interval" config is set to (say) 10 minutes, then post task completion my task is marked success but the respective dag it is present in, is marked success only after 10 minutes. Ideally, this should not happen. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: It is exactly what should happen. The DAG will be running at only every next min_file_process_interval.

Comment: But then as I described the situation above, increasing "min_file_process_interval" doesn't practically helps as it creates a new problem.

Comment: Why did you 'increase' the 'min_file_process_interval'? As you mentioned, the dag schedule has to be greater than min_file_process_interval. If you set the dag schedule interval as 1 min and min_file_process_interval, of course, it will not work. You need to set file_process_interval as 1 min or other value less than dag schedule interval.

Comment: I didn't explain myself properly. Let me try again.
Dag_schedule: 1 hour. 
min_file_process_interval = 10min. 
dag runs as per schedule. task in the dag completes in 1 min. so, the dag should also be marked success now. But no, that happens only after 10 mins (or whatever min_file_process_interval is set)

Comment: Yes, the behavior is exactly expected. My understanding: mark as success will be done every min_file_process_interval after the task was running and not return failure code. At each min_file_process_interval, airflow worker will do three type of things: a. check the previously running task's return code then mark it accordingly. b. check database and add corresponding tasks which scheduled in last time interval into pool. c. check tasks pool and launch these tasks one by one.

Comment: yes, I think that is the way. But then it makes more sense to keep min_file_process_interval unchanged to default value (which is 0). Or atleast as small as possible

Comment: Correct. As long as the server has enough resource, there is no reason to change the default value of min_file_process_interval.

Comment: sure. i have also accepted your answer. Thanks for your time and help :)